# Can't save any files into pdf now

Tags: macos, pdf, printing, file, adobe

I've been using Mac. Suddenly I can't save any files into pdf now.
Can't print a webpage into PDF; can't print a word into PDF; and can't even sign on a PDF and save. Even Word's "Save as" button doesn't work now.

Does anybody know why?

My Acrobat Adobe is in the latest version.

[image]

Comment: I found a bypass: instead of clicking save as, I click share -> send PDF so that I can send the converted pdf to my email address... This is so weird.

Comment: Rebuild the system? When did you last reboot?

Comment: On Windows PCs Acrobat is flaky and often loses functionality, reinstalling or running a repair from the Acrobat help menu usually fixes such issues. See if there is a similar 'repair' function in Acrobat for the Mac, possibly the Acrobat menu or under Help...

Comment: What does Adobe Acrobat Pro have to do with Words export/save options or with printing a webpage?

Comment: @SteveChambers what has a pc go to do with this? Op says mac as a tag...

Comment: @SolarMike Note the second sentence where I ask if there is a similar repair function on the Mac version of Acrobat. Don't use it or have it on my Macs, Preview works for me, hence the reason it's a comment not an answer.

Comment: Are you talking about a specific Acrobat method of creating PDFs, or are you talking about macOS's built-in PDF creation, e.g. in Safari, File > Export As PDF; and in the Print dialog (PDF button)? The two are totally separate. Can you describe the exact process, and what happens when you do it? Do you have a Printer queue set up?

Comment: @SolarMike rebooting didn't help :(

Comment: @benwiggy Safari also can't print any page as PDF, nor can it export as PDF!!!

Comment: Define "can't". What happens exactly? Is the menu item greyed out?, or is it black but nothing happens when you select it? Also what OS version are you on? Printer queue? Can you save a PDF from TextEdit? Preview?

Comment: nothing happens except a colorful spinning ball there. Monterey 12.6.  Can't save from TextEdit or previer as PDF - save spinning ball problem

Comment: restarting the computer with holding "shift" for safe mode actually made this problem disappear! But when I'm editing word documents I seem to be using a different user account now. Weird.